# cannot retrieve object from sharedpreference through Gson

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Hi I was saving an kotlin model into my sharedpreference now I cannot retrieve the data again,
this is my code :

```
val preferenceProvider = PreferenceProvider(context)
val userProfile = Gson().fromJson(preferenceProvider.getLastSavedAt("UserProfile"), UserProfile::javaClass)
```

In second line fromJson is not found, if replace `::javaClass` with `.class` then it is showing name expected what do I do ?

Comment: `UserProfile::class.java`

Comment: Thanks I tried and it is working now